# Issue while scrolling to last position RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually in my app i'm able to add from one recyclerView items to another and the another one show just 3 last added items until i collapse the bottom recyclerView to show more items.

For now i'm doing the following for scroll to the last position when i'm adding the items to the recyclerView

```
mRecyclerViewTOP.scrollToPosition(dummyDataItems.size() - 1);
```

And that work but at some point if i add child items to the last item from the recyclerView that doesn't scroll down even if i add the same command when i'm adding child item.

Like here i'm adding items to topRecyclerView

[image]

While here i've added child item to the last one

[image]

And that the full view of items with child view

[image]

So i would even if i add child item to make it scroll to show the last child item.